# Probability density functions and random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

$Y = g(X)$ where $X$ is Gaussian $N(0;s^2)$ and $g(x) = \min\{X+1,0\}+\max\{X-1,0\}$.

Find the
CDF $F(y)$ in terms of the “Q function”. Is $Y$ continuous, discrete, or mixed?

Comment: What do you mean by "the Q function"?

Comment: @RodrigoZepeda Presumably he means [$1-\Phi$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-function), where $\Phi$ is the standard normal CDF.

Comment: In statistics the inverse of $F$, $F^{-1}$ is often denoted $Q$.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/164788/expected-value-as-a-function-of-quantiles/164790#164790

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing $Y$ in terms of [Iverson brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket), we have 
$$\begin{align}
Y&=(X+1)[X+1<0]+(X-1)[X-1>0]\\ 
&=(X+1)[X<-1]+(X-1)[X>1].\\
\end{align}$$

Then
$$\begin{align}F(y)&=P(Y\le y)\\
&= P(Y\le y\ \cap\ X<-1) + P(Y\le y\ \cap\ -1\le X\le 1)+P(Y\le y\ \cap\ X>1)\\
&=P(X+1\le y\ \cap\ X<-1) + [y\ge 0]P(-1\le X\le 1)+P(X-1\le y\ \cap\ X>1)\\
&=P(X\le y-1\ \cap\ X<-1) + [y\ge 0]P(-1\le X\le 1)+P(X\le y+1\ \cap\ X>1)\\
&=[y-1\ge -1]P(X<-1)+[y-1<-1]P(X\le y-1) + [y\ge 0]P(-1\le X\le 1)+[y\ge 0]P(1<X\le y+1)\\
&=[y\ge 0]P(X<-1)+[y<0]P(X\le y-1) + [y\ge 0]P(-1\le X\le 1)+[y\ge 0]P(1<X\le y+1)\\
&=[y\ge 0]\bigg\{P(X<-1)+P(-1\le X\le 1)+P(1<X\le y+1)\bigg\}+[y<0]P(X\le y-1)\\
&=[y\ge 0]P(X<y+1)+[y<0]P(X\le y-1)\\ \\
&=[y\ge 0]\,\Phi\left(\frac{y+1}{s}\right)+[y<0]\,\Phi\left(\frac{y-1}{s}\right)\\
\end{align}$$
where $\Phi$ is the standard normal CDF. In terms of the ["Q function"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-function), i.e., $Q=1-\Phi$, we then have 
$$\begin{align}F(y)&=[y\ge 0]\,\left(1-Q\left(\frac{y+1}{s}\right)\right)+[y<0]\,\left(1-Q\left(\frac{y-1}{s}\right)\right)\\
&=1-[y\ge 0]\,Q\left(\frac{y+1}{s}\right)-[y<0]\,Q\left(\frac{y-1}{s}\right).\\
\end{align}$$

To answer your final question, consider how $F(y)$ behaves in the neighborhood of $y=0$, etc. Here's a picture of $F$ for the case $s=1$:

[image]